# Is 103424K an optimal SSD alignment and why?

Tags: ssd, alignment

I've seen many sites recommending to use 103424K "Offset/Alignment @ 4K Cluster", whatever it means. I understand the alignment in general, but my questions are

- what is "Offset/Alignment @ 4K Cluster"?
- why this strange number, which is no power of two nor a small multiple of one?

  ---

I looks like the alignment is actually

```
103424 KiB = 103424 * 1024 B = 101 * 2**20 B = 101 MiB
```

which is a multiple of 1 [MiB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix), which is fine according to the [SSD Alignment Calculator](http://www.techpowerup.com/articles/other/157), but still...  why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what is "Offset/Alignment @ 4K Cluster"?

It means that the offset should be a multiple of 4KB so that operations on the partition are aligned for devices with 4KB cluster sizes.

> why this strange number, which is no power of two nor a small multiple of one?

This is a multiple of 4KB that is large enough to leave enough room for a 100MB system partition before it.

Answer (score 0):

**4 KiB (4 Kibibytes = 4096 bytes) needs to be a factor of your *Partition Starting Offset*, for correct SSD partition alignment.**

---

**To check in Windows:**
*(I am assuming you are using Windows, as your post history suggests so.)*

- Run `msinfo32.exe` and find your SSD under `Components/Storage/Disks`.
- Find the `Partition Starting Offset` and divide that value by 4096.
- If the result is a whole number (no decimals), you are fine.

You don't actually have to worry about this anymore, as Windows does it automatically (since Windows 7, IIRC).

Comment: Can you address the "why" part?  Why "needs to be a factor of your Partition Starting Offset, for correct SSD partition alignment"?

Comment: @fixer1234 It's my understanding that the blocks of memory in SSDs are in 4096 byte units, so if they are not used fully, the SSD controller has to read or send chunks of data twice, to two blocks each time.  I may be wrong though (not thought about this for years).  I will look into it when I have a bit more time.  I'm just about to go out.

Comment: @paradroid so did you come back

Comment: @venimus No, I didn't.